# MySql max key too long with a key less then 767

Tags: mysql

Strange question, I have been creating database tables on my local mysql for years now, and I have just got an error message:

Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

The column at fault is the following:

```
`referenceperiod` VARCHAR(300) NULL
```

notice the length of 300, which, the last time I checked is less then 767.  I have an index on this column which if I remove allows the table to be built:

```
INDEX `idx_referenceperiod` (referenceperiod),
```

The strange thing is, this is not the first time I have built this exact table - so why is it suddenly failing now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a UTF8 collation, MySQL reserves 3 bytes for each character, in which case the key becomes 900 bytes in total.

900 is more than 767, last time I checked. ;)

Comment: You're absolutely right!  Why oh why oh why am I suddenly using UTF8 collation - the tables are generated programatically and the code has not changed for a very long time.  In any case, thank you for your answer it has solved my problem!

Comment: Maybe someone has changed the default collation of the database. If you (our your program) don't specify a collation specifically, that default is used.